# why docker image management create date is stale

Tags: docker

I'm trying to get a grasp on docker image/container management. I run the following commands after a build to help keep the disk space used down:

```
 docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
 docker images | awk '/^<none>/ {print $3}' | xargs docker rmi
```

This works well. I sometimes manually delete images using the image id. What escapes me, when I delete an image specifically is when it is recreated the created time reported is from the original created time frame. I would expect it to be the date it was created. For example:

```
 REPOSITORY               TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED                  VIRTUAL SIZE
 <none>                   <none>              4eb6a3fb4a76        5 days ago          1.587 GB
 user1/image1             latest              cc710febe57e        5 days ago          1.597 GB
```

Why is that? Is the image retaining items from the deleted image? I originally created the image 5 days ago. I expect it to have a new created value after creating the image today.

Also, a tip in case you don't know... using --rm with run cleans up containers after stopping.

Comment: I am experiencing the same.

Comment: Do you know about `docker system prune`, more precisely `docker container prune` and `docker image prune`?

Answer (score 0):

To remove unused images, containers, ... you can use the `prune` option.

For example:

```
docker container prune
docker image prune
docker network prune
docker volume prune
```

or

```
docker system prune
```